# Como inserir data atual no postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data

Preciso setar em uma coluna no `postgresql` a data atual da inserção como valor default para o campo.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910763/how-to-set-a-postgresql-default-value-datestamp-like-yyyymm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode setar o valor default na criação da coluna, por exemplo:

`my_date date not null default CURRENT_DATE`

Answer (score 1):

[Se sua tabela já existe você precisa fazer um update nela](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-alter.html#AEN2780)

```
alter table minha_table
alter column minha_date set default current_timestamp
```

[Se você esta criando você já pode criar a coluna com o valor default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910763/how-to-set-a-postgresql-default-value-datestamp-like-yyyymm)

```
create table minha_table
(
    minha_date  date not null default CURRENT_DATE
);

(CURRENT_DATE is basically a synonym for now() and a cast to date).
```